# Run part of code with elevated privileges on MacOS

Tags: macos, privileges

In my app I have some swift code that require elevated privileges (to perform some IO Connection - IOConnectCallStructMethod). I searched a lot on internet, and between 10-years old information, or some methods with helpers, I wonder if there was an Apple recommended way to perform so. I don't intend to distribute my code, it's for pure own need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it with the use of helpers thanks to this excellent guide: https://www.woodys-findings.com/posts/cocoa-implement-privileged-helper